# NLP nltk using the custom grammar

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, grammar

Hi let's imagine i have a grammar like this S-> NNP VBZ NNP . However the number of NNPs are huge and its in a file. How can I load that directly into grammar or how can I make sure that the grammar fetches the words from the corpus instead of specifying all the words ?

Comment: By "the grammar fetches the words from the corpus," do you mean you want to generate text based on the most likely next word?  e.g. start with a random NNP, pick the most likely VBZ and NNP to follow it?

Comment: Hey Clay , no I don't mean that. What I mean is I have a text file with say 1000 NNP i want the grammar to take up the words from the file instead of me explicitly mentioning like NNP -> "word1" | "word2" | ........

Comment: What do you want to use your grammar for? Is it for parsing or for text generation?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each POS has its own text file consisting of every possible word with that tag on a separate line, you just want to make a dictionary by reading in the lines:

```
lexicon = {}
with open('path/to/the/files/NNP.txt', 'r') as NNP_File: 
    # 'with' automatically closes the file once you're done
    # now update the 'NNP' key in your lexicon with every word in the file.
    # a set seems like a good idea but it depends on your purposes
    lexicon['NNP'] = set(NNP_File.readlines())
```

This setup is good for checking if some word can be of a specified part of speech; you could also flip it around and make the words the keys, if that's better for what you're building:

```
for word in NNP_File.readlines():
    if lexicon.has_key(word):
        lexicon[word].update(['NNP'])
    else:
        lexicon[word] = set(['NNP'])
```

If your text files are formatted a different way, you'll need to take a different approach.  **EDIT** To produce a grammar line in the format you mentioned, you could follow that first approach above with something like,

```
with open('path/NNP.txt', 'r') as f:
    NNP_terminal_rule = 'NNP -> ' + '|'.join(f) 
    # str.join() takes an iterable, so the file object works here.
```